# Why does libm-2.x.so not install on 22.04 with `build-essential`?

Tags: shared-library

This is mostly a curiosity, since I ended up ultimately using `libm.so.6` in my app, but

I just noticed that on ubuntu 22.04, the shared library version of `libm` does not appear to be installed in the `build-essential` package.  Is this intentional? Is this particular version no longer supported? Can a `libm-2.x.so` be installed directly (via `apt`, e.g.)?

### To recreate:

The following dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
CMD cd /usr/lib && find -type f -name libm-*
```

produces the following output:

```
$ docker run libmtest
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.35.a
```

whereas if we switch the base image to `ubuntu:20.04`, we see the .so is found as expected

```
$ docker run libmtest                                                                                       
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.so                                                                                                                             
./x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.31.a
```